# Send events to different GA accounts

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm very new to GTM and GA4, so please bear my ignorance, and I need to send conversion events to two accounts/tags: ours (e.g. G-1111111) and our client's (e.g. G-2222222)

According to the docs, I should do something like this for an **"add_to_cart"** event:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-1111111">
</script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  // Global configs
  gtag('config', 'G-1111111');
  gtag('config', 'G-2222222');

  // Route ecommerce add_to_cart event to Google Ads and Analytics
  gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
    'items': [
      'id': 'U1234',
      'ecomm_prodid': 'U1234',
      'name': 'Argyle Funky Winklepickers',
      'list': 'Search Results',
      'category': 'Footwear',
      'quantity': 1,
      'ecomm_totalvalue': 123.45,
      'price': 123.45
    ]
  });
</script>
```

Since both the **G-1111111** and **G-2222222** are assumed to be in the "default" group, it's assumed both Gtags would receive the event.

But there's something I'm not sure about. We are loading this URL:

https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-1111111

Should we also load the one for the second GTag?:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-2222222">
```

And even more on this. What GTM id should we specify in the GTM snippet? Ours (e.g. GTM-AAAAAA) our client's (e.g. GTM-BBBBBB), both of them??

```
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){
      w[l]=w[l]||[];
      w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
    var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),
        dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
    j.async=true;
    j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer',"GTM-AAAAAA");
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, this is quite messy. You're all over the place here. First, decide whether you want all your implementation to be in GTM, or gtag. Pick one. Having it all in GTM is the best practice. Having it all in gtag is ok for tiny implementations where you don't have analysts on the team. Mixing the approaches is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I believe the gtag id= is just to have it load one of the tags automatically. If you look at the network events you will see it makes another request for the tag with the other id afterwards.

Comment: Hi @BNazaruk, how should I proceed only using GTM? Can I use the same API, that is, window.DataLayer?

Comment: Yes, you can and should still use DL with GTM, but you use it directly, so via window.dataLayer.push() and you push the objects with event names and other things you need to track, which is described better here: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/datalayer then after you push your stuff to DL, it's not automatically tracked. You'll have to log in into your GTM container and add tags, triggers and variables that you want so that all that logic would start firing on your DL pushes. While doing so, you want tear down any gtag reference from your FE code.

Comment: The idea behind GTM is to make your tracking inheritable, maintainable, scalable and all those sweet words. Using gtag directly is in 99% of cases just a dirty approach where you don't care about the big concepts, you just need it to work here and now and don't have time or need to do stuff properly. GTM uses gtag behind the scenes. It also loads gtag seamlessly when needed.